# beginning nodejs, filesystem and contents of the main folders

Tags: node.js

I have installed nodejs and node-red on linux, please, could you explain what the following folders contain?

```
~/.npm/
~/.npm-global/
~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/
```

Answer (score 1):

**npm** short for Node Package Manager, is a cli tool for managing node dependencies

**~/.npm** is the npm cache directory.  See: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#cache

**~/.npm-global** is where dependencies that are available system-wide are stored.  See: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally